# Future of luatex and pstricks

Tags: pstricks, luatex

As far as I know it is not (yet) possible to use pstricks directly with luatex (-> pdf) as for example in xelatex.

Are there any plans to implement this in luatex in near future? If so, how is the state of this? If not, what are the problems?

Naively I think it should be possible to make luatex recognize a pstricks environment and start separate thread which compiles the pstricks picture and includes it automatically as a vector graphic into the pdf.

Given that luatex is the successor of pdflatex, I think it should be a very desirable goal to have working pstricks and pgf in one document out of the box with one engine.

Comment: LuaTeX is not the successor to pdfTeX: the fact that LuaTeX is (deliberately) not 100 % back-compatible rules this out.

Comment: your description minimises the interactiion between tex and pstricks, pstricks used with classic tex integrates postscript code with the postscript generated from the tex so the end result is that tex typeset text is mixed (or manipulated) by postscript, this does rather rely on the assumption that there is some postscript generated from the tex....

Comment: see escrito project: http://escrito.luatex.org/ it is postscript interpreter for LuaTeX. it seems dead unfortunately :(

Comment: For Lua(La)TeX There will be, hopefully, the same as for MetaPost: `\PSTricks <the code> \endPSTricks`

Comment: What is unclear in this question? Please tell me, then I can edit it to make it clearer.